# Autofac shared objects require different registrations per controller but InstancePerApiControllerType won't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

As detailed in [InstancePerApiControllerType not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24789391/173225), I am unable to use the `InstancePerApiControllerType` to configure my solution. The answer provided there works so long as I am directly injecting a `ConnectionContext` into the controller, or otherwise know that a class is only used by a specific controller. Unfortunately that is not the case in my situation:

```
ControllerA -> EngineA -> RepositoryA -> GenericEntityAccessor

ControllerB -> EngineB -> RepositoryB -> GenericEntityAccessor
```

The issue is when we come in through `ControllerA`, `GenericEntityAccessor` needs "string A" and from `ControllerB` it needs "string B".

Of course, the real situation is a little more complicated and there are some bad practices such as code that directly "news"-up a `ConnectionContext` (it's legacy code). I'm currently exploring providing another component that provides the connection string that is injected via Autofac and configured in the controller using Lazy, but the bad practices are causing problems there also (i.e. once I start to change things in the interface, all the dominoes start to fall over and I end up 15 classes later wondering how I got there).

Are there any patterns, techniques, etc. that address this type of thing? I can't imagine it's all that uncommon.

UPDATE:

To provide a few more specifics, since I'm having some trouble getting this to work, in general we have the following hierarchy, showing which scopes I've applied

```
Controller -> InstancePerApiRequest()
I*Repository -> ?
I*Manager -> ?
I*Builder -> ?
I*Adapter -> ?
ISqlServerConnectionContext -> ?
IConnectionContextCache -> InstancePerApiRequest()
```

I've got a number of components that directly take ISqlServerConntectionContext and I'm trying to provide it like so:

```
container.Register(c =>
{
    var connectionContextCache = c.Resolve<IConnectionContextCache>();
    var connection = (ISqlServerConnectionContext)connectionContextCache.CurrentConnectionContext;

    return connection;
}).As<ISqlServerConnectionContext>().InstancePerDependency();
```

Unfortunately at that point I'm getting a null for CurrectConnectionContext. My guess at this point is I've got some component that isn't rooted from the controller and I'm currently going through the dependencies manually attempting to find it (AFAIK the isn't a way for my to find out which object triggered Autofac to attempt to provide the ISqlServerConnectionContext when I'm debugging).

UPDATE 2:

It turns out I did have some issues where I was registering things improperly, and creating a dependency on `ISqlServerConnectionContext` for `DocumentController`, even though it did not have one (this was created through the delegate for something it did depend on).

Now I've got a circular reference that I'm pretty sure I've created myself in the registrations:

```cs
container.Register(x =>
{
    if (x.IsRegistered<HttpRequestMessage>())
    {
        var httpRequestMethod = x.Resolve<HttpRequestMessage>();

        var tokenHelper = x.Resolve<ITokenHelper>();
        var token = tokenHelper.GetToken(httpRequestMethod);

        return token ?? new NullMinimalSecurityToken();
    }

    return new NullMinimalSecurityToken();
}).As<IMinimalSecurityToken>().InstancePerApiRequest();

container.Register(c =>
{
    var connectionContextCache = c.Resolve<IConnectionContextCache>();
    var token = c.Resolve<IMinimalSecurityToken>();
    var connection = (ISqlServerConnectionContext)connectionContextCache.CurrentConnectionContext;

    connection.Token = token;

    return connection;
}).As<ISqlServerConnectionContext>().InstancePerApiRequest();
```

The problem is `ISqlServerConnectionContext` has a property of type `IMinimalSecurityToken` which is optional, and definitely not used when the `ISqlServerConnectionContext` is being used to look up `IMinimalSecurityToken`, which depends on `ISqlServerConnectionContext` through `ITokenHelper`.

UPDATE 3:

For completeness, in order to solve my circular reference problem I needed to use named services, and use a `SqlServerConnectionContext` that did not have the `IMinimalSecurityToken` property set for the `IOAuthTokenManager` registration. Now I'm getting the dreaded

> No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible

error, but I think that warrants a new question if I'm not able to solve it.

```cs
container.Register(c =>
{
    var productId = WellKnownIdentifierFactory.Instance.GetWellKnownProductIdentifier(WellKnownProductIdentifiers.RESTSearchService);
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppSettingsNames.DatabaseConnection];

    var newConnectionContext = new SqlServerConnectionContext(connectionString) { ProductID = productId };
    newConnectionContext.Open();

    return newConnectionContext;
}).Named<ISqlServerConnectionContext>("OAuthTokenConnectionContext").InstancePerApiRequest();
container.Register(c => new SqlServerBuilderFactory(c.ResolveNamed<ISqlServerConnectionContext>("OAuthTokenConnectionContext"))).Named<IBuilderFactory>("OAuthTokenBuilderFactory").InstancePerApiRequest();
container.Register(c =>new OAuthTokenManager(c.ResolveNamed<IBuilderFactory>("OAuthTokenBuilderFactory"))).As<IOAuthTokenManager>().InstancePerApiRequest();
```

Comment: Is it possible to put null referencing checks in the CurrentConnectionContext property and include the current StackFrame method name in a thrown InvalidOperationException ?

Comment: Could be that you have registered the cache as perlifetimescope. Remember that perlifetimescope in a web context is actually the root scope and not scoped to the request. Try updating to perapirequest as per your controllers. Just seen my answer made this mistake! Apologies that was an auto complete bug and I'll update ASAP.

Comment: See this question regarding debugging AutoFac resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578942/how-can-i-log-all-resolve-requests-to-autofac-container

Comment: I was wondering about the PerLifetimeScope on the cache. Switched that and still getting the same issue. Adding the current StackFrame method in the exception is just giving me something along the lines of <Register>b__f. Basically I can see the container is having a problem, but not which bit of the configuration is causing it. I did  new up a connection in that method with a bad connection string in hopes of figuring out which component gets it. That's where I'm at now, trying to figure out which one it is.

Comment: Thanks for the updates - very puzzling. The fact that PerApiRequest is not throwing an AutoFac resolution exception is useful to know as it shows that all dependents on the Cache are infact scoped by the request. Any singletons or dependents outside of the request scope would be getting a resolution exception of some kind.

Comment: Just to confirm with your code - is the Cache responsible for creating the connection? Is this first constructed in your controller and does your controller in anyway reference an ISqlServerConnectionContext dependency? Could you put a little more code up around these two areas?

Comment: Yes, the cache is creating the connection and setting the ```CurrentConnectionContext```. What appears to be happening is Autofac is running the delegate that registers ```ISqlServerConnectionContext``` _before_ executing the controller which is where the factory (and the cache) gets created.

Comment: I think at least one of the issues is that I have ```DocumentController -> IConnectionContextFactory -> IConnectionContextCache```. ```IConnectionContextCache``` returns ```IConnectionContext```. I have other components that depend on ```ISqlServerConnectionContext -> IConnectionContext``` but Autofac doesn't know that the ```DocumentSearch``` controller needs to be run before ```IConnectionContextCache.CurrentConnectionContext``` will be initialized. However, if I attempt to resolve ```Document Controller``` in the delegate, I get a circular reference error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using AutoFac's support for object graph lifetime scoping.

1. Cache the current `SqlServerConnectionContext` in an object scoped to the lifetime of your controller.
2. Within the `SqlServerConnectionContext` factory type, once the connection is created assign it to the backing field of the current lifetime-scoped cache
3. Any types scoped within the lifetimes scope of a controller can then access the connection associated with that controller through the cache

The only complexities I can think of are:

1. If the controller is **not** actually the root of a lifetime scope for all types with a dependency on a specific connection. I.e. if they fall outside the lifetime of the controller.
2. If any of the dependencies are registered as single instance. In which case they will not be able to resolve the Cache as it is currently implemented as it is PerApiRequest.

For example:

```
public interface ISqlServerConnectionContextCache
{
    ISqlServerConnectionContext CurrentContext { get; set; }
}

public class SqlServerConnectionContextScopeCache : ISqlServerConnectionContextCache
{
    public ISqlServerConnectionContext CurrentContext { get; set; }
}

public interface ISqlServerConnectionContextFactory
{
  ISqlServerConnectionContext Create();
}

// The factory has the cache as a dependancy
// This will be the first use of the cache and hence
// AutoFac will create a new one at the scope of the controller
public class SqlServerConnectionContextFactory : ISqlServerConnectionContextFactory
{
  private string _connectionString;
  private ISqlServerConnectionContextCache _connectionCache;

  public SqlServerConnectionContextFactory(ISqlServerConnectionContextCache connectionCache,
    string connectionString)
  {
    _connectionCache = connectionCache;
    _connectionString = connectionString;  
  }

  public ISqlServerConnectionContext Create()
  {
    var connectionContext = new SqlServerConnectionContext(_connectionString);
    connectionContext.Open();
    _sqlServerConnectionContextProvider.CurrentContext = connectionContext;
    return connectionContext;
  }
}

public class MyController : ApiController
{
  private ISqlServerConnectionContext _sqlServerConnectionContext;

  public MyController(Func<string, ISqlServerConnectionContextFactory> connectionFactory)
  {
    _sqlServerConnectionContext = connectionFactory("MyConnectionString");
  }
}

// As the cache is lifetime scoped it will receive the single instance
// of the cache associated with the current lifetime scope
// Assuming we are within the scope of the controller this will receive
// the cache that was initiated by the factory
public class MyTypeScopedByController
{
    public MyTypeScopedByController(ISqlServerConnectionContextCache connectionCache)
    {
        var sqlServerConnectionContext = connectionCache.CurrentContext;
    }
}

// AutoFac wiring
builder.RegisterType<SqlServerConnectionContextScopeCache>()
    .As<ISqlServerConnectionContextCache>()
    .InstancePerApiRequest();
builder.RegisterType<SqlServerConnectionContextFactory>()
    .As<ISqlServerConnectionContextFactory>()
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

Comment: That looks like it's going to get me going in the right direction. I don't think I'll need to worry about things being outside of the lifetime scope of the controller. If there are any, it likely will indicate an error in configuring them.

Comment: Should work fine - AutoFac lifetime scoping is a joy to use. We use it for all sorts of things - my favourite being providing a logging context within a business transaction. Any problems just report back and I'll take a look.

Comment: I've added some more details to the question. I think I do have some non-controller rooted objects, but it's possible I've just messed things up some other way.

Comment: Theres a bug in my answer (now fixed) where the Cache was being registered as PerLifetimeScope. Within the context of a web request, this actually scopes the dependency to the **root** scope and hence is a singleton. Looking at your updated question, I see you are also using PerLifetimeScope - which would definitely cause issues. I also wonder if you have set this because PerApiRequest didn't work? If so this is a sure sign some of the types with a dependency on the cache are single instance. I've updated my answer to include this as well.

Comment: What I seem to be having trouble with is (in your example) wiring up MyScopedByController, although in my case I've got a lot of classes I can't (easily) modify that depend on ISqlServerConnectionContext and I'm trying to register that by a delegate. i.e. how do I do it "within the scope of the controller"?

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect the fact that InstancePerApiRequest is not working either.

Comment: How about using a service locator type approach to resolve the cache from types that you can't use di on? Maybe even just a GetCurrent static method on the cache and get the cache to use autofac to resolve itself in the right scope?

Comment: The problem isn't that I can't use DI on some types, it's that those types are expecting a connection context to be injected, not a cache, and since they are in a shared library also used in other projects that are not being converted to Autofac, I can't very well go and modify their interfaces.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since it does solve my original problem. The circular reference issue I'm now dealing with is, I believe, a completely separate issue.

Comment: Sorry been really busy so not had a chance to look any further. Good luck finding the root cause.